# Comparing boolean subexpressions for equality in SQL (Microsoft SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use the following logical expression as part of a stored procedure for Microsoft SQL Server 2012, where `@filter1` and `@filter2` are of type `bit` (i.e. boolean).

```
((@filter1 <> 0) = (T.ID = '123')) and
((@filter2 <> 0) or (T.FK is null))
```

I get a syntax error at the first `=`. Evidently results of boolean terms can be combined using `AND` and `OR` but cannot be checked for equality with other such terms.

Is this indeed the case and if so, how would one normall reformulate such a condition for this SQL environment? Do I have to compare something like `case when TERM then 1 else 0 end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves me right you can't evaluate the assignment operation as a boolean value (in the way you can in C for instance) so I think you would have to do this:

```
((@filter1) = (case when T.ID = '123' then 1 end)) and
((@filter2 <> 0) or (T.FK is null))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
(((@filter1 <> 0) AND (T.ID = '123')) OR ((@Filter1 = 0) AND (t.ID <> '123'))) and
((@filter2 <> 0) or (T.FK is null))
```